# Repeat values with in the GROUP in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to repeat a row value in the subsequent rows with in GROUP. A Group can have one or more TAG. The requirement is to populate NEW_TAG in the row where the TAG is populated and in the subsequent rows until another TAG populated with in the same group or we reach end of that GROUP.

```
Current Table      Required Table

GROUPID SEQ TAG    GROUPID SEQ TAG NEW_TAG
------- --- ----   ------- --- --- --------
1       1           1       1       
1       2           1       2       
1       3           1       3       
1       4   4       1       4   4   4
1       5           1       5       4
1       6           1       6       4
1       7           1       7       4
1       8           1       8       4
2       1           2       1       
2       2           2       2       
2       3           2       3       
2       4           2       4       
2       5   5       2       5   5   5
2       6           2       6       5
2       7           2       7       5
2       8           2       8       5
2       9   9       2       9   9   9
2      10           2      10       9
2      11           2      11       9
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the tag always increasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming TAG is always increasing

```
max(TAG) over
(
    partition by GROUPID 
    order by     SEQ 
    rows         between unbounded preceding
                 and     current row
) as NEW_TAG
```

---

```
select  *
       ,max(TAG) over
        (
            partition by GROUPID 
            order by     SEQ 
            rows         between unbounded preceding
                         and     current row
        ) as NEW_TAG

from    mytable
;
```

---

```
+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| groupid |  seq   |  tag   | new_tag |
+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| 1       | 1      |        |         |
| 1       | 2      |        |         |
| 1       | 3      |        |         |
| 1       | 4      | 4      | 4       |
| 1       | 5      |        | 4       |
| 1       | 6      |        | 4       |
| 1       | 7      |        | 4       |
| 1       | 8      |        | 4       |
| 2       | 1      |        |         |
| 2       | 2      |        |         |
| 2       | 3      |        |         |
| 2       | 4      |        |         |
| 2       | 5      | 5      | 5       |
| 2       | 6      |        | 5       |
| 2       | 7      |        | 5       |
| 2       | 8      |        | 5       |
| 2       | 9      | 9      | 9       |
| 2       | 10     |        | 9       |
| 2       | 11     |        | 9       |
+---------+--------+--------+---------+
```